# Reimporting a library in IntelliJ

Tags: java, android, maven, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm having difficulties in restoring a library(.jar) file to a gradle project in IntelliJ idea. I was using the library(**kiaraparser-0.1.0.jar**) and noticed some bugs in the code. 
I've fixed the issues, rebuilt the project(**kiaraparser**) and exported it as a .jar file. I then removed the dependency(the entry in the **lib** directory), in project in which I'm using the respective library(**kiaragen**) "safely" so that it could later be restored. 
Afterwards, I added the new version of the library as an external library but noticed that I forgot to export a number of dependencies and now get errors as:

```
/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/src/main/java/org/fiware/kiara/generator/sergen.java
Error:(20, 24) java: package com.eprosima.log does not exist
Error:(33, 32) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable ColorMessage
  location: class org.fiware.kiara.generator.sergen.TemplateErrorListener
Error:(39, 32) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable ColorMessage
  location: class org.fiware.kiara.generator.sergen.TemplateErrorListener
/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/src/main/java/org/fiware/kiara/generator/idl/grammar/Context.java
Error:(23, 36) java: package com.eprosima.idl.parser.tree does not exist
Error:(24, 36) java: package com.eprosima.idl.parser.tree does not exist
Error:(25, 36) java: package com.eprosima.idl.parser.tree does not exist
Error:(26, 40) java: package com.eprosima.idl.parser.typecode does not exist
Error:(27, 40) java: package com.eprosima.idl.parser.typecode does not exist
Error:(28, 40) java: package com.eprosima.idl.parser.typecode does not exist
Error:(29, 40) java: package com.eprosima.idl.parser.typecode does not exist
Error:(30, 40) java: package com.eprosima.idl.parser.typecode does not exist
Error:(37, 54) java: package com.eprosima.idl.context does not exist
Error:(75, 42) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TypeCode
  location: class org.fiware.kiara.generator.idl.grammar.Context
Error:(159, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Interface
  location: class org.fiware.kiara.generator.idl.grammar.Context
```

Reverting to the old(buggy) library by undoing the deletion(click on **lib** --> VCS --> Local History --> Show History, revert) puts **kiaraparser-0.1.0.jar** back in the **lib** directory but does not seem to include it in the build process(I also removed the "new" version of the library which was  added as an external library).

The **lib** directory now looks like:

[image: kiara_ild_lib]

The only thing I notice is the blue font of the library name. How may I restore and add the old library to the classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, IntelliJ deletes the library from the project, it does not remove it. The revert operation creates an empty file in the **lib** with the same name as the library that has been removed.

The issues were caused by a number of differences between the default library used by the project(**kiaraparser-0.1.0.jar**) and its current version.

I have managed to solve the issue by creating a new project from files belonging to both versions of the library using [this](http://jd.benow.ca/) tool to retrieve the source files of the default library.